# How do I block google suggest through my firewall?

Tags: google, block

Im using cyberoam enterprise firewall. But I think this is a general question...I just want to know what port number or url I need to block to disable google suggest across the company.

Comment: I know this is besides the point but why would you want to do that ?

Comment: Yeah, this is one of those "please, please tell us the story behind this question" ones!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When making a request, something like this gets send:

```
http://clients1.google.co.uk/complete/search?client=chrome&output=chrome&hl=en-US&q=MYKEYWORD
```

So you should probably block `http://client1.google.*/complete`

Comment: This is not working